# only eliminate certain duplicates in data in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2013, trying to remove certain duplicates from a set of data.  I need to prioritize the data where "field 5" is "2" however if there isn't a duplicate or a "2" I need to keep the data where the field is "1".

Current State Data

```
|Field1 |Field 2| Field 3| Field 4 |Field 5|
|AAA    | BBB   | CCC   | DDD      |1      |
|AAA    | BBB   | CCC   | DDD      |2      |
|III    | JJJ   | KKK   | LLL      |2      |
|XXX    | YYY   | ZZZ   | TTT      |1      |
|MMM    | NNN   | OOO   | PPP      |1      |
|MMM    | NNN   | OOO   | PPP      |1      |
```

Desired State

```
|Field1 |Field 2 |Field 3 |Field 4 |Field 5|
|AAA    |BBB     |CCC     | DDD    |2      |
|III    |JJJ     |KKK     | LLL    |2      |
|XXX    |YYY     |ZZZ     | TTT    |1      |
|MMM    |NNN     |OOO     | PPP    |1      |
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of some question, but the suggested question does not appear to be an appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think the simplest method is conditional aggregation.  For your particular data, this works:

```
select field1, field2, field3, field4,
       max(field5) as field5
from t
group by field1, field2, field3, field4;
```

This is not necessarily a general solution to the problem you describe.  But it appears to be what you want to accomplish with your data.  For instance, this assumes that `field5` only takes on the values `1` and `2`, as in the sample data.

Comment: And why would an answer that appears to correctly address the OP's question be downvoted?  Anonymously?

Comment: Good question. +1.